# How to combine within-subject score for between analysis when there is no within ID

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I was task with analyzing some within/between-subject data, but my current guess is that I have no way of analyzing a combined within-subject score since an identifier/ID is missing. Is there a different way to how to do significance testing between groups for a overall score?

Given are 2 tables (t), t1 has first rating (1-7 scale) of participants, t2 has second rating of participants (after several hours of an intervention), 5 different treatments.

While (between-subject) significance testing for either t1 or t2 data separately is straight forward, my guess is I have no way of analyzing the 'overall rating' (combined within t1 and t2 rating).

I could get mean, sd, ci for each t1 and t2, but I cannot do significance testing on that data without (wrongly, of course) treating the within-subject scores independently.